How to read last message from specific contact from "Messages" application and display on touch bar?
I'm using BetterTouchTool and i wanted to display recent message from a specific contact from Messages app into touchbar with button click from touchbar. Here's what i have tried:
Create trigger -> Touch Bar Button)
Assign Action -> Run Apple Script (blocking)
Script:
use framework "Foundation"
use scripting additions

property contactName : "Amor" -- Replace with the desired contact name

on run
    try
        tell application "Messages"
            set targetChat to first chat where name of participants contains contactName
            if targetChat is not missing value then
                try
                    set messageList to messages of targetChat
                    if (count of messageList) > 0 then
                        set latestMessage to item 1 of messageList
                        set messageContent to content of latestMessage
                        set outputString to "Latest Message:  " & messageContent
                    else
                        set outputString to "No messages found in the conversation with " & contactName
                    end if
                on error errMsg
                    set outputString to "Error accessing messages: " & errMsg & return & "Chat ID: " & (id of targetChat as string) & return & "Participants: " & (name of participants of targetChat as string)
                end try
            else
                set outputString to "No conversation found with " & contactName
            end if
        end tell
    on error errMsg
        set outputString to "Error: " & errMsg
    end try
    
    -- Display the output
    display dialog outputString buttons {"OK"} default button "OK"
    
    -- Also return the output for use in Script Editor's result pane
    return outputString
end run


It gets compiled and gives the below error while running script. Can someone help me fix this issue please?
Error accessing messages: Messages got an error: Can’t make messages of chat id "iMessage;-;+6140*******" into type specifier.

